# text file search yyyy/mm/dd and replace with yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: text-processing, replace

I have a file with many tags in the form of `yyyy/mm/dd` as in the line below and want to replace the `/` with `-` to give `yyyy-mm-dd` at all instances in the one file.
e.g.

from this: `<tag k='start_date' v='2011/01/01' />`
to this: `<tag k='start_date' v='2011-01-01' />`

I'm on Mac 10.11.6

Comment: are you able to install xml/html parsers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` for that

```
$ sed -E 's|([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})|\1-\2-\3|g' file
```

Give a try.

To edit the file in place, with macOS or FreeBSD, add a `-i ''` option. Most of other `sed` implementations need `-i` alone for that (`-i.back` would work for both and save the original with a `.back` extension). On systems where `sed` doesn't support in-place editing, you can use `perl -pi -e` in place of `sed -E` (which inspired those `sed -i`).

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, no it did not work.
The text is unchanged

But this worked fine ...

```
perl -pi -e 's|([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})|\1-\2-\3|g' file
```